# Position a div inside another with fixed and now "white space"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do something like:

[image]

This is how far I know:
http://jsbin.com/apikiw/3/edit#preview

The problems is that I can't put it between the `<p />` because it's dynamic content... how I can solve that?

Thank you!

Comment: please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate: as you can see, the image has text over the "quoted" text (the bold one with "). In my example, I can't get text over that quotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have given looks like it has a "float:right;" style on the quotation.
If this is dynamic, you will need to mark is as different to the rest of the content somehow.

This is what I did v quickly:
http://www.cyba.co/test.html

Note in the HTML that the quoted section appears just before the section it's indented into. If this text is marked as the heading for that section, this is how you should structure the HTML.

[Edited to show CSS and jQuery]

```
.1-post-content p {
    display:block;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $quotation=$('.1-post-quotation').clone();
    $('.1-post-quotation').remove();
    $quotation.insertAfter('.1-post-content p:nth-child(1)');
}
```

Notes:
This is the principal, but of course you still need to tailor it to your needs, e.g. how the data changes for each usage, identifying where to put the quoted part, etc.
Also if you do use jQuery, don't forget to include the jQuery script file!

I don't want to assume too much - are you ok with where to add the CSS and script?

Comment: Hello @bukko, thank you for your code. The problem is that the content (the `<p />`s) comes autogenerated by PHP. I don't ever know how many they are because I just have a `<?php echo $content; ?>`. That is why I positioned the `<div />` with the quote over that content and this is why I'm asking if there is anyway that is not including directly to the code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can format the <p> tags with css anyhow you like. Are you able to identify the ones you want to format in this way? If so, just change the display to block and they pretty much become <div>s. Also don't forget you can add elements anywhere you want dynamically. If you can supply the raw HTML you get, maybe I can help more.

Comment: Assuming the example you supplied is an example of your raw HTML, you can achieve what you want by adding the style ".1-post-quotation p" with "display:block;". You also need to move the quoted <p> element to where you want it embedded. Probably easiest with jQuery.

Comment: I have added another example here: www.cyba.co/test1.html that does exactly what you're asking, I think. It starts with HTML like you have shown (I shortened the class names) and converts it to the desired output. I have embedded the CSS and jQuery to hopefully make it clear.